# How to fix compatibility issue with JSR-303 validation and orientdb

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, orientdb

We are trying to use orientdb 1.7.8 in our project, but we are hitting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getProviderUtil
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.jpa.OJPAPersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil(OJPAPersistenceProvider.java:80)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:78)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:34)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:60)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.CachingTraversableResolver.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolver.java:82)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConstraintValidation.isReachable(ConstraintValidation.java:241)
    ... 158 more
```

This occurs because we are using jsr-303 validation in our project (which is currently actually non-jpa). The validation library scans for JPA persistent manager, which Orientdb provides in its orient-object jar. We want to use the object framework for orientdb in the future as well, so excluding it is not an option.

The JPA PersistentceProvider implementation of OrientDB seems incomplete:

```
public class OJPAPersistenceProvider implements PersistenceProvider {

    .... implemented all other methods ...

    @Override
    public ProviderUtil getProviderUtil() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getProviderUtil");
    }
```

Now the validation jar automatically picks up this class, as the orientdb-object jar has the javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider file in META-INFO/services.

So, is there a workaround for this? Or will orientdb support the getProviderUtil method so it can play nice with jsr 303 validation? Is there maybe some way to have the validator ignore this particular jpa implementation?

Changing the jsr implementation to use the hibernate validation implementation gives the 
exact same exception.

Comment: A problem of using something that is not a real JPA implementation perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, the orientdb jpa implementation is not complete. I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Create the file META-INF/validation.xml (or update it). And add something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">

    <traversable-resolver>MyValidationTraversableResolver</traversable-resolver>

</validation-config>
```

And the implementation of the custom resolver:

```
public class MyValidationTraversableResolver extends DefaultTraversableResolver {

    public MyValidationTraversableResolver() {
        //we simply override the constructor to disable jpa detection
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReachable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class<?> rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCascadable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class<?> rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What normally happens is that when JPA is enabled, the validation framework checks via JPA that a bean property can be validated. This just disables these checks and assumes everything is always validatable.

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
 <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
 <version>${orientdb.version}</version>  
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-object</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 

</dependency>
```

Comment: That wont work. This would remove the object api altogether, but I still need that api.